# How do I get the total time it took from boot for a service to start?

Tags: systemd, services

I need to measure the total time with millisecond resolution that it took for a machine to boot and start a service.

I attempted to do `systemd-analyze critical-chain name.service`. That provided me with a number, but I happened to check it against `systemd-analyze plot > plot.svg`. The critical chain version of the command leaves off the kernel startup time and it looks like the initrd time as well. The plot provides me what I want, but I'd like to not have to view a graph or parse the svg and do the math to convert the x axis position to seconds.

Is there a command to get the time from boot until a particular service was started?